# How to query pandas dataframe using a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with the following contents:

```
    A   B     C  D
0 red, t1, blue, 1
1 red, t1, yellow, 2
2 red, t0, green, 1
3 red, t0, blue, 1
4 red, t0, blue, 2
5 green, t1, yeallow, 1
6 green, t0, red, 1
7 green, t0, yellow, 1
8 blue, t0, yellow, 1
9 blue, t1, red, 1
10 yellow, t1, red, 3
```

How to extract all the rows that for `A` equal to `'green'` AND for `B` equal to `t0` for example?

Comment: `df[df.A.str.contains("green") & df.B.str.contains("t0")]` since you used the word "contain". If you want exact matching, `df[(df.A == "green") & (df.B == "t0")]`

Comment: Please add this as an answer.

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640129

Comment: I do not like how the question is formulated in the link you provided. So, I think it is better to have a separate question with an example and a short answer, as given by @ayhan

Comment: This will not detect the colors in column C, but you can adjust the approach as follows. Define `set_of_needed_words`. Write `df = df[df.apply(lambda s: s.isin(set_of_desired_words))]`.

Comment: @minerals It is not a problem to be a dupe. Now this post will serve as a signal to the other, Not something to worry about. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As answered by @ayhan,**

Partial string match:

```
df[df.A.str.contains("green") & df.B.str.contains("t0")]
```

Exact string match:

```
df[(df.A == "green") & (df.B == "t0")]
```

Comment: This works, but obviously only for columns `A` and `B`. So the row like `['red', 't1', 'green', 0]` will be omitted. I am not clear if this is in line with your intent.

Comment: Sorry, in my question I meant exactly that (corrected the question).