# Delete rows if rows (not columns separately) contain a string

Tags: python, pandas, csv, lambda, contains

I import data from a CSV where I am replacing the empty fields with an 'EMPTYFIELD' value.

```
pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', usecols=['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'])
df =  df.fillna('EMPTYFIELD')
```

I am trying to create a dataframe that will have all the rows that contain an 'EMPTYFIELD' value. That implies that at least one column contains this value. I used the following and it works off course:

```
error = df[df.AAA.str.contains('EMPTYFIELD')]
error = error[error.BBB.str.contains('EMPTYFIELD')]
error = error[error.CCC.str.contains('EMPTYFIELD')]
```

Now, I am trying to reduct the lines in my code. So, I was thinking of using a lambda instead without referencing to the columns (ideal):

```
error2 = df.apply(lambda x: 'EMPTYFIELD' if 'EMPTYFIELD' in x else x)

#error2 = df.apply(lambda x : any([ isinstance(e, 'EMPTYFIELD') for e in x ]), axis=1)
```

and then I tried referencing the columns too:

```
error2 = df[usecols].apply(lambda x: 'EMPTYFIELD' if 'EMPTYFIELD' in x else x)
```

and

```
error2 = df[df[usecols].isin(['EMPTYFIELD'])]
```

None of the above work. I print the results in a new CSV file. I can see all the rows even if they contain the 'EMPTYFIELD' value.

UPD: This is my extended code. Some of the answers return an error possible because of the lines below:

```
varA      = 'AAA';
dfGrouped = df.groupby(varA, as_index=False).agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max'}).copy()

varsToKeep = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'Start Date_grp', 'End Date_grp' ]
dfTemp = pd.merge(df, dfGrouped, how='inner', on='AAA', suffixes=(' ', '_grp'), copy=True)[varsToKeep]
```

errors =  dfTemp[~np.logical_or.reduce([dfTemp[varsToKeep].str.contains('EMPTYFIELD') for varsToKeep in dfTemp])]

Comment: "Now, I am trying to **reduct** the rows" What does this mean?

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you want to delete the rows with the bad field, why not just do `df[~df.AAA.str.contains('EMPTYFIELD')]`?

Comment: @pault I do not want to reference to the column names. AAA is one of the columns.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Reduce the code lines. Fixed ;)

Comment: @pault I could use a for loop checking for the usecols to do that. But I prefer the code not to refer to the column names.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer, I'm not sure if there's another way. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26641085/5858851). However, if you do not replace the empty values with `"EMPTYFIELD"`, you may be able to use [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Comment: @pault `dropna()` is useful. But, I need also the opposite of the `dropna()` as I want to present both in two different files.

Comment: You can use `dropna()` to create a second DataFrame. Then filter the first one using the index of the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `np.logical_or.reduce`. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
                   ['G', 'A', 'D', 'I'],
                   ['L', 'K', 'A', 'J'],
                   ['S', 'T', 'U', 'V']],
                  columns=['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3' ,'COL4'])

df[~np.logical_or.reduce([df[col].astype(str).str.contains('A') for col in df])]

#   COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
# 1    E    F    G    H
# 4    S    T    U    V
```

Comment: @Tried that. I am getting an error possibly because this (UPDATE in my question) affects the code.

Comment: `Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: @ApoloRadomer. OK, it explains itself. I've updated code now for you to try.

Comment: Neat and tidy. I will search the exact logic behind this. I mean each "command" does.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an illustration of how to use `dropna()` as I [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812441/delete-rows-if-rows-not-columns-separately-contain-a-string#comment84628857_48812441):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [5,3,5,6], 
     'B': [None, "foo", "bar", "foobar"], 
     'C': ["foo","bar",None, "bat"]
    }
)
no_errors = df.dropna()
errors = df[~(df.index.isin(no_errors.index))]
```

Which results in the following 2 dataframes:

```
print(no_errors)
#   A       B    C
#1  3     foo  bar
#3  6  foobar  bat

print(errors)
#   A     B     C
#0  5  None   foo
#2  5   bar  None
```

Now if you want, you can call `fillna()` on the error DataFrame.

Comment: That works if I first use the `dropna()` and then `group by` before printing. Based on one column (A), let's say we have an ID 11111. We have 5 rows for this ID without empty fields. Then we have 1 row of which one column (B) has an empty value. I want all the 6 rows for this ID to count as an error.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention using `apply` , data from jp

```
df[~df.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('A')).any(1)]
Out[491]: 
  COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
1    E    F    G    H
4    S    T    U    V
```

Comment: That returned an error: `('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index AAA')`. Before using your line, I am grouping by and then I am using the following: `pd.merge(df, dfGrouped, how='inner', on='AAA', suffixes=(' ', '_grp'), copy=True)[varsToKeep]`