# Finding Table Name and Column Name for string

Tags: python

I have to search string in database , suppose i don't have column name and table name , i have to find all the column name and table name in whole database.I want to do it with  Python or pandas , please suggest a efficient and faster way to do it as i have huge amount of data .I have the table which contains table name and column name.

All_table ---It contains all the table.
all_tab_columns ---It contains all the table with their corresponding names

Comment: What do you mean by huge? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for String in all Pandas DataFrame columns and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640129/search-for-string-in-all-pandas-dataframe-columns-and-filter)

Comment: By huge I means it contains bulk amount of data, I think by SQL joins it will be a time taking process and by pandas I have to load the whole database in database ,so it will be time and  memory taking process. I want  to do it in dynamic way to do it

Comment: Is it possible with SQL archemy