# How to open an Excel file then save values to doc or pdf?

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas, ms-word

How do I execute a script that

- opens an Excel file
- searches for a value (there are many in the file so I would like to make a random copy)
- copies it to pdf / doc and saves
- goes to the next Excel file and repeats the same operation (all data from Excel must be saved in one pdf / doc.

My Excel file structure:

[image: value]

I want to export the data to pdf / doc for which the value is 1.

I started writing the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file_loc = "location of xlsx file"
df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A:AA")
print(df)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search entire excel sheet with Pandas for word(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657853/search-entire-excel-sheet-with-pandas-for-words)

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a package called **python-docx**

This might get you started

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/