# How can I Optimize a search in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to search the word 'mas' in Dataframe, the column with frase is Corpo, and the text in this column is splitted in list, for example: I like birds ---> split [I,like,birds]. So, I need search 'mas' in a portuguese frase and catch just the words after 'mas'. The code is taking to long to execute this function.

```
df.Corpo.update(df.Corpo.str.split()) #tokeniza frase
df.Corpo = df.Corpo.fillna('') 

for i in df.index:
  for j in range(len(df.Corpo[i])):
    lista_aux = []

    if df.Corpo[i][j] == 'mas' or df.Corpo[i][j] == 'porem' or df.Corpo[i][j] == 'contudo' or df.Corpo[i][j] == 'todavia':
        lista_aux = df.Corpo[i]
        df.Corpo[i] = lista_aux[j+1:]
        break

    if df.Corpo[i][j] == 'question':
        df.Corpo[i] = ['question']
        break
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640129/search-for-string-in-all-pandas-dataframe-columns-and-filter

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide an example input and expected output in your question. You can read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with `pandas` dataframes (or `numpy` arrays) you should always try to use vectorized operations instead of for-loops over individual dataframe elements. [Vectorized operations are (nearly always) significantly faster than for-loops.](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

In your case you could use pandas built-in vectorized operation [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), which allows extraction of the string part that matches a regex search pattern. The regex search pattern [`mas (.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ipEyCN/1) should capture the part of a string that follows after 'mas'.

```
import pandas as pd

# Example dataframe with phrases
df = pd.DataFrame({'Corpo': ['I like birds', 'I mas like birds', 'I like mas birds']})

# Use regex search to extract phrase sections following 'mas'
df2 = df.Corpo.str.extract(r'mas (.+)')

# Fill gaps with full original phrase
df2 = df2.fillna(df.Corpo)
```

will give as result:

```
In [1]: df2
Out[1]:
              0
0  I like birds
1    like birds
2         birds
```

Comment: In case that the phrase don't have the word 'mas', how can I add the original phrase instead the 'NaN'?

Comment: With a [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) operation for example. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Xukrao you helped me so much!