# Pandas - find specific value in entire dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to search all columns for values that is text 'Apple'. I know how to do it with one column, but how can I apply this to ALL columns? I want to make it a function, so that next time I can directly use it to search for other values in other dateframes.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640129/search-for-string-in-all-pandas-dataframe-columns-and-filter

Comment: `(df=='Apple').sum()`
This will give the number of rows in all columns where the value = 'Apple

Answer (score 22):

You can try searching entire dataframe using the below code:

```
df[df.eq("Apple").any(1)]
# if using pandas version >=1.5, passing positional argument was deprecated
df[df.eq("Apple").any(axis=1)]
```

Using `numpy` comparison

```
df[(df.values.ravel() == "Apple").reshape(df.shape).any(1)]
```

Timing (pandas version 1.5.2):
While the .ravel() approach is initially quicker on smaller datasets, using .eq() is faster on larger datasets.

```
small_df = pd.DataFrame({"A":list(range(500)), "B":list(range(500, 1000))})
large_df = pd.DataFrame({"A":list(range(100000)), "B":list(range(100000, 200000))})
largest_df = pd.DataFrame({"A":list(range(1000000)), "B":list(range(1000000, 2000000))})

def filter_df_by_value_eq(df, value):
    return df[df.eq(value).any(axis=1)]

def filter_df_by_value_ravel(df, value):
    return df[(df.values.ravel() == value).reshape(df.shape).any(1)]

In [8]: %timeit filter_df_by_value_eq(small_df, 612)
175 µs ± 1.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit filter_df_by_value_ravel(small_df, 612)
78.9 µs ± 215 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit filter_df_by_value_eq(large_df, 1502964)
307 µs ± 2.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit filter_df_by_value_ravel(large_df, 1502964)
1.56 ms ± 13.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit filter_df_by_value_eq(largest_df, 10502964)
3.04 ms ± 66.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [13]: %timeit filter_df_by_value_ravel(largest_df, 10502964)
15.2 ms ± 43.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 12):

Something like this:

```
In [1188]: df
Out[1188]: 
   id   name      n1
0   1   Zeke     may
1   2  Apple    maya
2   3      a   Apple
3   4   Maya       a
4   5  Derek  Mayank
5   6     an      is
6   7    the     the
```

Just have a check like:

```
In [1190]: df[df == 'Apple']
Out[1190]: 
   id   name     n1
0 NaN    NaN    NaN
1 NaN  Apple    NaN
2 NaN    NaN  Apple
3 NaN    NaN    NaN
4 NaN    NaN    NaN
5 NaN    NaN    NaN
6 NaN    NaN    NaN
```

OR

```
In [1191]: df.where(df == 'Apple')
Out[1191]: 
   id   name     n1
0 NaN    NaN    NaN
1 NaN  Apple    NaN
2 NaN    NaN  Apple
3 NaN    NaN    NaN
4 NaN    NaN    NaN
5 NaN    NaN    NaN
6 NaN    NaN    NaN
```

This lets you search through all the columns of a dataframe.

Answer (score 12):

## import pandas library

```
import pandas as pd
```

## Raw Data or URL of file

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Mihir', 'Mihir', 'Raju', 'Johan', 'Johan'],
               'last_name': ['Patel', 'Patel', 'Ali', 'Khan', 'Khan'], 
               'age': [42, 42, 36, 24, 53]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'])
```

## Find The Value

```
df.loc[df['first_name']=='Mihir']
```

Comment: This finds the value from a single column. The OP specifically asked for a solution that searched the entire df.

Answer (score 1):

Search list of values in given dataframe all columns:

```
filter_data = df[df.isin(['Apple', 'Green Apple']).any(1)]
```

Search single value in given dataframe all columns:

```
filter_data = df[df.contains('Apple').any(1)]
```

Comment: Are you refering to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html ?  Because dataframe does not have any "contains" method

Comment: What does `any(n)` do?

Comment: no .contains method.  Tito was correct.

Comment: The `isin()` is quite quick. But the `.contains()` only works on a single column and needs to be prefixed by the column name and `.str` e.g. `df.name.str.contains()`

Answer (score -9):

Take what you have for your single method and include in the for loop.

```
for column in df:
    #your code here
```