# python find specific value in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to get a specific value in a dataframe that is composed of two columns, Date and Close.
what I need is a close value of a specific date.

As a first step, I tried to find a specific date in the date column using the code below, but I keeps failing.

```
df[df['Date'].isin([specific_date])]
```

I can't come up with any better idea than this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this stack question:
[Pandas - find specific value in entire dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587315/pandas-find-specific-value-in-entire-dataframe)

```
df.loc[ df['Date'] == specific_date ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it before, and when I print the result, it says empty dataframe. I don't know  what the problem is.

Comment: can you give me the dataframe to find a solution for you?

Comment: Thanks it solved. The problem is the date was not in the dataframe. I thought every date is in df.

Comment: my pleasure to help.