# How to find a cell address from larger csv file around 350 MB for particular search value using Python pandas etc

Tags: python, pandas, chunks

I have tried different ways to get by using for loop, xlwings,etc but it is taking long time to open or process. Is there any fastest way to read csv files and get cell address of an value?

Comment: the fastest way is probably to use c/c++ .... `pandas.read_csv` is pretty quick to ... but for this task you will get many wins using c/c++ (ie you can exit early once you find your match) I cant answer if the cost of using C/C++ for this task outweighs any potential benefit

Comment: What about loading your csv into a sqlite database and use its indexing feature?

Comment: That iill work how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640129/search-for-string-in-all-pandas-dataframe-columns-and-filter This above link helps me find the answer of this question.