# Python Pandas df.loc problem with True and False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("path", sep = " ")
newdf = df.loc[:,:].isin(["(#10)","#9","Automation","Create","log"])
print(newdf)
```

This is my code. I have a big logfile where I want to look for different error codes ["(#10)","#9","Automation","Create","log"] in the whole file.

The file has 16124 rows and 70 columns.
The code itself works, but the problem I have is that the output is only "True" and "False". I want the output to be the actual words from the file.
Can anyone help me?

The poutput I get is:

1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8   ...
0      False  False  False  False   True  False  False  False  ...
1      False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  ...
2      False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  ...
3      False  False  False  False  False  False  False  True...

[16124 rows x 70 columns]

The output I want it all rows with the error codes in every column.

1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8   ...
3      2022-06-21 14:20:25 65891 DEBUG Concern    #8  nonlog ...
8      2022-06-21 14:20:25 65891 INFO  Automation #8  nonlog ...
71     2022-06-21 14:20:25 65891 INFO  Concern    #9  nonlog ...
358    2022-06-21 14:20:25 65891 INFO  Concern    #8  log    ...

[4 rows x 70 columns]

Comment: `df.where(newdf)`? See [pd.DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). You'll get your original df with values where condition is `True`. Where condition is `False`, you'll get `NaN` values by default. But you can change them into something else with the `other` parameter, e.g.: `df.where(newdf, other="empty")`. If you are looking for a different (perhaps more specific) output, please be more specific in your question, and add some sample *input* and *expected output* data.

Comment: You may try searching on a specific column `df.loc[df['specific_column_to_search_in'].isin(["(#10)","#9","Automation","Create","log"])]` this should give you the desired result

Comment: @SanidhyaSingh It works like you said for one column. But I have about 70 columns...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SteffiRi is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640129/search-for-string-in-all-pandas-dataframe-columns-and-filter

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.column_stack([df.loc[:,:].isin(["(#10)","#9","Automation","Create","log"])])
df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
```

adapted from this answer
[Search for String in all Pandas DataFrame columns and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640129/search-for-string-in-all-pandas-dataframe-columns-and-filter)

Comment: thanks, this worked for me now:                                                                                           
`df[  
    df.select_dtypes(object)
    .apply(lambda row: row.str.contains("with"), axis=1)
    .any(axis=1)
`

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this method

```
newdf = df[df.isin(["(#10)","#9","Automation","Create","log"])].dropna()
print(newdf)
```