# Is there a Python pandas function for retrieving a specific value of a dataframe based on its content?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I've got multiple excels and I need a specific value but in each excel, the cell with the value changes position slightly. However, this value is always preceded by a generic description of it which remains constant in all excels.

I was wondering if there was a way to ask Python to grab the value to the right of the element containing the string "xxx".

Comment: Maybe this will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640129/search-for-string-in-all-pandas-dataframe-columns-and-filter

Answer (score 1):

try iterating over the excel files (I guess you loaded each as a separate pandas object?)
somehting like `for df in [dataframe1, dataframe2...dataframeN]`.

Then you could pick the column you need (if the column stays constant), e.g. - `df['columnX']` and find which index it has:
`df.index[df['columnX']=="xxx"]`.  Maybe will make sense to add `.tolist()` at the end, so that if "xxx" is a value that repeats more than once, you get all occurances in alist.

The last step would be too take the index+1 to get the value you want.

Hope it was helpful.
In general I would highly suggest to be more specific in your questions and provide code / examples.